# How to Render PDF file with PDFJS, Gulp and Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, pdf.js

I'm trying for a few days to render a simple pdf using the pdfjs plugin but it seems so esoteric to do this following the instructions that i have found in the different guides (i mean to me im extremely new with the plugin and specially with Webpack).

I have been following this example:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website

I have already downloaded a build into my workspace with npm, i have the pdfjs-dist into my node_modules, i understand that i have to require pdfjs-dist into my gulp.js and i have the viewer.html and a local host running BUT when i opened the viewer.html in the browser i can't see the PDF. I have not change var DEFAULT_URL = 'compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf' in the viewer.  .js since that file is inside the same folder.

Im getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Neither `require` nor `window` found
    at Object.<anonymous> (viewer.js:513)
    at __webpack_require__ (viewer.js:35)
    at Object.pdfjsLib (viewer.js:90)
    at __webpack_require__ (viewer.js:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (viewer.js:1189)
    at __webpack_require__ (viewer.js:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (viewer.js:7772)
    at __webpack_require__ (viewer.js:35)
    at viewer.js:81
    at viewer.js:84
```

Any help will be really appreciated.